# ToolKit DataGrid deselect all on LostFocus

Tags: wpf, datagrid, toolkit

I'm trying to create a style which will make all my DataGrids select row -1 when they lose focus. I'm doing:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.LostFocus">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(DataGrid.SelectedIndex)">
                        <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-1" />
                    </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It works only for the first time the focus is lost, but on the second time program crashes because of type conversion ecxeption. Is it possible without code behind?

Comment: Are you just trying to remove the selected item from the `DataGrid`?

Comment: I'm trying to remove selection (select nothing).

Comment: It might be worth re-titling your post to state your *actual* goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my researches, attached behavior is the only acceptable solution for me. Hope this will help somebody more:

```
public class DataGridBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDeselectOnLostFocusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsDeselectOnLostFocus", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = dependencyObject as DataGrid;
        if (dg == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            dg.LostFocus += dg_LostFocus;
    }

    static void dg_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (sender as DataGrid).SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    public static bool GetIsDeselectOnLostFocus(DataGrid dg)
    {
        return(bool)dg.GetValue(IsDeselectOnLostFocusProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsDeselectOnLostFocus(DataGrid dg, bool value)
    {
        dg.SetValue(IsDeselectOnLostFocusProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="helpers:DataGridBehavior.IsDeselectOnLostFocus" Value="True"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve your *actual* goal of de-selecting the selected item is to bind an object of the same type as those in the collection data bound to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property to the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property. When you want to deselect the selected item, you simply set this object to `null`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Item}" />
```

In view model:

```
Item = null; // de-selects the selected item
```

Comment: Thanks, it is clear, but I just wanted a style to achive that behaviour in all my DataGrids.. And what should I do onLostFocus..? Go to VM? Use System.Windows.Interactivity to run commands on events..? It is too complicated.. imho